# Win32 function to tell if a file is descendant of directory

Tags: windows, path, filesystems, windows-shell

In C++, Windows, I have 2 file paths:

- **Path1**: Directory
- **Path2**: File or Directory

How can I tell if Path2 is a descendant of Path1?  Is there a Shell function for that?  I have searched the Shell API and could not find any.

Note: I don't want to compare the string myself, unless there is a safe way to make the path comparable (handle short names, relative items, etc...).

Comment: @shellter: `wsh` refers to Windows Scripting Host, and has nothing to do with the Shell API.

Comment: @gabe, I've removed my useless comment. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [PathCommonPrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773574%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to compare the two paths to get a common prefix. Then compare the common prefix to Path1 (your directory).

If the two are equal then Path2 should be a descendant.

Or you maybe able to get away without using an `out` buffer and just pass `NULL` for the third parameter and check that the return value, which is the count of common prefix characters, is equal to Path1's length.

From the `PathCommonPrefix`'s doc's example, it doesn't look like `PathCommonPrefix` includes trailing directory separators in the 'common' prefix, so you'll have to strip off the trailing sep in Path1 or adjust your comparison of the result accordingly for lack of trailing sep.

Comment: Thanks, Initially, after reading the summary of the function in MSDN I thought it would not work, but after reading the example, I see it should work.  (and it's verified, it works!)

Comment: @decasteljau You'll need to canonicalize your paths to make it really work. For example, input of C:\trick and C:\trick\.. results in a common prefix of C:\trick which is not right. Also you do realise don't you that this will fail in the presence of junction, symlinks etc. Perhaps that's OK for you but I just want to make sure you are clear on the limitations of this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there is a handy function in the API to answer this for you.  But I also don't think it's too hard to write a robust function to do this.  Here's the outline:

1. Makes sure that Path1 and Path2 are absolute paths.
2. Check if Path1 and Path2 refer to the same file system object (more on this below).
3. If so then your function returns true.
4. If not strip the last name off Path2, i.e. remove the final path separator (\ or /) and everything that follows it.
5. If step 4 failed to remove any text (e.g. there are no path separators left) then you have reached the root level and your function returns false.
6. Go to 2.

Now, how to check that two names refer to the same file system object. The safest way to do so is to call [`GetFileInformationByHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364952%28VS.85%29.aspx) for both names, and compare `dwVolumeSerialNumber`, `nFileIndexLow`, `nFileIndexHigh`. If all are equal then the two names refer to the same object.

Note that it's not enough to compare strings because a single file system object can have many different names. For example hardlinks, symlinks, junctions, UNC vs mapped drive letters and so on.

Comment: @Gabe I'd call [PathIsRelative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773660(VS.85).aspx) and if that returns true then you'd need to make it absolute (e.g. combine with the current directory or whatever it is that your app decrees the path is relative to).

Comment: You also have to remove any `..` segments of your path without walking past your root directory.

Comment: @Gabe That's a good point. A couple of calls to [`PathCanonicalize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773569(VS.85).aspx) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that I came up and that seems to work so far (in my limited testing).  It tests whether the file is a direct descendant, and also obtains the relative path.  It's based on [`PathRelativePathTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathrelativepathtow).

```
BOOL PathDirectRelativePathTo(LPWSTR pszPath, LPCWSTR pszFrom, DWORD dwAttrFrom, LPCWSTR pszTo, DWORD dwAttrTo)
{
    return PathRelativePathTo(pszPath, pszFrom, dwAttrFrom, pszTo, dwAttrTo) && pszPath[1] == L'\\';
}
```

The premise is that when a file is a direct descendant, the relative path obtained by `PathRelativePathTo` starts with `.\`.  When it's not a direct descendant, the relative path starts with `..`.  So this function tests whether the second character of the relative path is a `\`.  But again, I just came up with this, so perhaps there are some problems lurking in there somewhere.